# How to use file lock mechanism provided in SI for file reading

Tags: spring-integration

I have one file which SI reads from folder but my application is deployed on two clusters so that file is being read two times so i used file locker mechanism provided in spring Integration but in that case what i found is that my files are not processing at all. what i am missing ?

UPDATE :I am using FileLocker class in this way using FileInbound adapter

```
private FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec readFilefromDirectory(){
        return Files.inboundAdapter(getInboxDirectory())
                .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                .locker(asFileLocker)
                .preventDuplicates();
    }

@Component
public class ASFileLocker implements FileLocker{
    @Autowired
    Properties properties;

    @Override
    public boolean lock(File fileToLock) {
        try{
            if(properties.getProperty("fileName").equalsIgnoreCase(fileToLock.getName())){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                properties.setProperty("fileName", fileToLock.getName());
                return true;
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLockable(File file) {
        String fileName= properties.getProperty("fileName");
        if(fileName.equalsIgnoreCase(file.getName())){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void unlock(File fileToUnlock) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the file content you have to use `FileChannel` from the `FileLock`.

But there is no access to that object from the `NioFileLocker`.

Consider to use `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` instead.
With shared `MetadataStore`, of course. In this case your file will be picked up only by one instance of your application.

Comment: i have updated my question with code which i am using .is this correct ?

Comment: Your code does not make sense. It doesn't lock anything and it isn't thread-safe. Why just don't follow with the recommendation and don't use `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#file-reading ?